# AngularJS form vaidate with radio buttons and ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, json, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to validate a form that is dynamically generated with JSON data, that is rendered to the page using ng-repeat. The data is questions with corresponding answers. The issue I'm running in to is that with a dynamic ng-model on each group, like so:

```html
  <div class="well question-well" ng-repeat="question in Posttest1Questions">
   
   <p><strong>{{question.question}}</strong></p>
   
   <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="answers in question.answers">
     <input type="radio" name="Q{{question.id}}" ng-model="question_[question.id]" id="{{question.id}}" value="{{answers.id}}" required data-key="{{answers.isCorrect}}">{{answers.answer}}
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

Even when all the questions are answered, the form never turns valid. In turn, if I remove the ng-model attr, the form is always valid, even if no radio buttons has been selected.

Example Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/DvcJ8byS0yF7iLp37Ets?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underscore in
`ng-model="question_[question.id]"` seems wrong to me.

Please try `ng-model="question[question.id]"` then you can simply say `required`

updated your plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/gCZHFqd07880Os8FcxhG?p=preview

Comment: Yep. Removing the underscore works. Didn't realize that underscores were not allowed in ng-model names.

Comment: yeah. for me the most logical way would be using `ng-model="question.answer"`. I have updated the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/gCZHFqd07880Os8FcxhG?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ng-required` to set a condition on the input's `required` status. In this case, if the model used with `ng-model` is null, then required. Otherwise, not required.

This way, once you've selected one of the answers (the model has a value), all of the answers for this question will not be marked as required.

```
<input type="radio" name="Q{{question.id}}" ng-model="question[question.id]" id="{{question.id}}" value="{{answers.id}}" ng-required="question[question.id] == null" data-key="{{answers.isCorrect}}" />
```

See it working [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HLOOfuVB27QMiK0BbY4a?p=preview).